# Python Webcolors - No Defined Color Name

Tags: python, opencv

I want to get the name of the hexadecimal color value using [webcolors](https://webcolors.readthedocs.io/en/1.11.1/).

I have run a single image for each specification `css2`, `css21`, `css3`, `html4`.

Each time I've run, I have the following errors:

```py
'#30403c' has no defined color name in css3
'#d4b6c0' has no defined color name in css3
'#8e7766' has no defined color name in css3

'#30403c' has no defined color name in html4
'#d4b6c0' has no defined color name in html4
'#8e7766' has no defined color name in html4
.
.
```

Here is the [Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE8ky.jpg)

Here is the code I'm using for producing the error:

```py
import cv2
import webcolors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from collections import Counter


# Source: https://gist.github.com/kb22/f17e59a79d4fcca02188c23cca932be5#file-rgb2hex-py
def rgb2hex(c):
    return "#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}".format(int(c[0]), int(c[1]), int(c[2]))  # format(int(c[0]), int(c[1]), int(c[2]))



def hex2name(c):
    h_color = '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(int(c[0]), int(c[1]), int(c[2]))
    try:
        nm = webcolors.hex_to_name(h_color, spec='css3')
    except ValueError as v_error:
        print("{}".format(v_error))
        nm = h_color
    return nm


img = cv2.imread("img/landscape.jpg")
img2 = img.reshape(img.shape[0] * img.shape[1], 3)
color = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
lbl = color.fit_predict(img2)
cnt = Counter(lbl)
center_color = color.cluster_centers_
ord_color = [center_color[i] for i in cnt.keys()]
hex_color = [rgb2hex(ord_color[i]) for i in cnt.keys()]
lbl_color = [hex2name(ord_color[i]) for i in cnt.keys()]
plt.pie(cnt.values(), labels=lbl_color, colors=hex_color)
plt.show()
```

The conclusion is the produced hexadecimal values are not present in the current specifications.

Therefore, is it possible to select the available hexadecimal value which is closest to my the current hexadecimal value?

Or any other solutions are appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Not all colors have web names. For 24-bit color there are 256*256*256 (over 16 million) possible colors. But there are only on the order of 100 named colors. Perhaps you want to find the closest named color.

Comment: Thats true I want to find closest color name

Comment: compute the rmse difference between your test color and the color values of all of the color names. Take the one with the smallest rmse.  You will need to convert from hex to r,g,b to do the rmse computation.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, I appreciate your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could get the closest image as @fmw42 suggested. (Thank you very much sir, I appreciate your suggestion.)

- > compute the rmse difference between your test color and the color values of all of the color names. Take the one with the smallest rmse. You will need to convert from hex to r,g,b to do the rmse computation.

For each image name, hexadecimal value, convert each hexidecimal value to the rgb.

```py
for img_clr, img_hex in webcolors.CSS3_NAMES_TO_HEX.items():
    cur_clr = webcolors.hex_to_rgb(img_hex)
```

Compute Root-Mean-Square-Error (RMSE)

```py
rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(c, cur_clr))
```

where `c` variable is our current `rgb` value.

Store it in the list

```py
rms_lst.append(rmse)
```

Get the closest image names' index

```py
closest_color = rms_lst.index(min(rms_lst))
```

Get the name of the image

```py
nm = list(webcolors.CSS3_NAMES_TO_HEX.items())[closest_color][0]
```

Example:

[image]

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import sys
import glob
import webcolors
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from collections import Counter


# Source: https://gist.github.com/kb22/f17e59a79d4fcca02188c23cca932be5#file-rgb2hex-py
def rgb2hex(c):
    return "#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}".format(int(c[0]), int(c[1]), int(c[2]))  # format(int(c[0]), int(c[1]), int(c[2]))


def hex2name(c):
    h_color = '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(int(c[0]), int(c[1]), int(c[2]))
    try:
        nm = webcolors.hex_to_name(h_color, spec='css3')
    except ValueError as v_error:
        print("{}".format(v_error))
        rms_lst = []
        for img_clr, img_hex in webcolors.CSS3_NAMES_TO_HEX.items():
            cur_clr = webcolors.hex_to_rgb(img_hex)
            rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(c, cur_clr))
            rms_lst.append(rmse)

        closest_color = rms_lst.index(min(rms_lst))

        nm = list(webcolors.CSS3_NAMES_TO_HEX.items())[closest_color][0]
    return nm


img = cv2.imread("img/landscape.jpg")
img2 = img.reshape(img.shape[0] * img.shape[1], 3)
color = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
lbl = color.fit_predict(img2)
cnt = Counter(lbl)
center_color = color.cluster_centers_
ord_color = [center_color[i] for i in cnt.keys()]
hex_color = [rgb2hex(ord_color[i]) for i in cnt.keys()]
lbl_color = [hex2name(ord_color[i]) for i in cnt.keys()]
plt.pie(cnt.values(), labels=lbl_color, colors=hex_color)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Good work. Minor points: you computed the MSE not the RMSE. But the MSE is sufficient. Saves a SQRT. Also if you are taking the pow to degree 2 (squaring), then I don't think you would need to take the abs first. Alternately, you can just multiply the difference by itself to get the squared value. Again, all these comments are trivial points.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, I will be more careful next time. Your precious suggestion enables me to solve my question. Kindly regards

Comment: Your code is fine. No need to be more careful. These were just suggestions if you need to make your code more efficient. Thanks for posting your solution.